Is WebRTC SFU frontend or backend?
I am woking on a livestreaming web app using react vite on frontend and django rest on backend.
I've managed to make a p2p connection using websocket and webRTC.
The Problem is to handle multiple peers.
I have reached to the concept of SFU, but I do not know how to use it and is it for frontend or the backend or both?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
